# computing RMSE using fitted model as input to function rather than $residuals

Tags: r

What I am trying to do is to write a function that will calculation RMSE, BIC and AIC of a fitted model in regression:

```
fit_lm <- lm(rnorm(50) ~ rnorm(50, 4))
summary(fit_lm)
```

When I pass the fitted model into AIC() and BIC(), I can get the results:

```
# BIC   
BIC(fit_lm)

# AIC
AIC(fit_lm)

# RMSE
rmse <- function(err) { 
          sqrt( mean ( err^2 ) ) 
        }
```

But here I have to pass `$residual` :

```
rmse(fit_lm$residuals)
```

What I should do to get rmse result only passing the fitted model something like:

```
rmse(fit_lm)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply adjust your function:

```
rmse <- function(mod) { 
          sqrt( mean ( mod$residuals^2 ) ) 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this (a generalized version):

```
rmse <- function(mod, which = NULL)
{
    if (is.null(which)) which <- 1:length(residuals(mod))
        sqrt(mean(residuals(mod)[which]^2, na.rm = TRUE))
}

rmse(fit_lm)
```